# (Multi-Threading Python) Print 1 to 10 numbers alternatively, using two threads

Tags: python, multithreading, deadlock

Please help me in resolving below Deadlock situation while printing 1 to 10 numbers alternatively, using two threads.

And please tell me the best practices to avoid deadlock situation in multi-threading python.

```
from threading import *

c = Condition()

def thread_1():
    c.acquire()
    for i in range(1, 11, 2):
        print(i)
        c.notify()
        c.wait()
    c.release()
    c.notify()

def thread_2():
    c.acquire()
    c.wait()
    for i in range(2, 11, 2):
        print(i)
        c.notify()
        c.wait()
    c.release()


t1 = Thread(target=thread_1)
t2 = Thread(target=thread_2)

t1.start()
t2.start()
```

Comment: Use different flags instead of using only one.

Comment: Your example does not show that the two `Thread` are dependant of each other. Therefore you don't need any `Condition`. [Edit] your questions code to show otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is rarely useful to have threads move in lockstep with each other.  If you really needed them to, you could use two separate events, as alluded to by Prudhvi.  For example:

```py
from threading import Thread, Event

event_1 = Event()
event_2 = Event()

def func_1(ev1, ev2):
    for i in range(1, 11, 2):
        ev2.wait()  # wait for the second thread to hand over
        ev2.clear()  # clear the flag
        print('1')
        ev1.set()  # wake the second thread

def func_2(ev1, ev2):
    for i in range(2, 11, 2):
        ev2.set()  # wake the first thread
        ev1.wait()  # wait for the first thread to hand over
        ev1.clear()  # clear the flag
        print('2')

t1 = Thread(target=func_1, args=(event_1, event_2))
t2 = Thread(target=func_2, args=(event_1, event_2))

t1.start()
t2.start()
```

In terms of avoiding deadlock, there has been much written on the subject already.  In your specific code example, `t1` will fire up before `t2` and get as far as `c.wait()`. `t2` will fire up and get as far as `c.aquire()`. Both will sit there indefinitely.  Avoiding deadlock means avoiding situations where both threads wait for the other.